# How to use OpenLayers in Node.js

Tags: openlayers, node-js

I am new in programming so it maybe that my question is not so professional. I am going to make an OpenLayers application with Node.js. I have installed Node.js and then install OpenLayers with npm install ol. I have node modules now. Then I made a main.js file and wrote this commands:

```
const ol = require('ol')
const fs = require('fs')
```

but apparently the OpenLayers can not be imported with this method. I insist an using require('ol') instead of import * as ol from ol. How can I fix this?

(note: I know that I can use import methods that are common in openlayers website examples. To do that I have to change the type of my js codes to module in package.json and use import * from ol. But then i can not use backend capabilities of node js like fs = reuire('fs'). I need the openlayers and node backend capabilities together. Maybe there is a way that i dont know because I am new in programming)

Comment: Why not simply following the doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol ?

Comment: Have a look at https://openlayers.org/doc/quickstart.html. Here you can read: _OpenLayers is packaged as a collection of ES modules. The import lines are used to pull in the modules that your application needs. Take a look through the examples and API docs to understand which modules you might want to use._

Comment: I followed that but as I said if i want to use openlayers with the method that you said, I have to change the type to module in package.json to use openlayers and use import * from ol. But then i can not use backend capabilities of node js like fs = reuire('fs'). I need the openlayers and node backend capabilities. Maybe there is a way that i dont know because I am new in programming

Comment: Then edit your question and add your additional explanation from your comment.